# Linq C#: Get value from list of class objects if in list of strings

Tags: c#, list, linq, class

I've been trying to get the first matching value from a list of objects within a list of objects that does not exist in a list of strings, but can't seem to find just the right syntax.

```
public class SO_Response
{
    private List<SalesOrderDto> _headers = new List<SalesOrderDto>();

    public List<SalesOrderDto> Header
    {
        get { return _headers; }
        set { _headers = value; }
    }
}
public class SalesOrderDto
{
    public SalesOrderDto(string order, string resultMessage)
    {
        Order = order;
        ResultMessage = resultMessage;
    }

    public string Order { get; }
    public string ResultMessage { get; }
}
```

Use in method:

```
     var result = new List<IRMS_SO_Response>();
    //result = .....

    var matches = new HashSet<string>() { "Good Record", "Order is canceled", "status = Cancelled" };

   --> Need Linq statement to get first value from result where header.ResultMessage not in matches.
```

I've tried lots of variations, but never the right one.

```
   var returnMessage = (from x in result
                        where x.Header.FirstOrDefault(message => !message.ResultMessage.Contains(matches))
```

Comment: You say "_that exists in a list of strings_" yet you do `!message.ResultMessage.Contains`, note the negation of the `Contains` using the `!` operator. Have you tried `where x.Header.FirstOrDefault(message => matches.Contains(message))`?

Comment: Ugh, sorry, yes, I meant the first message that is NOT in that list.

Comment: If I understood your comment right, then `Header.FirstOrDefault(message => !matches.Contains(message))` should work, right?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that I fully understand what you're looking for.  Assuming that you're looking for the first ResultMessage value which is not in the matches set, I believe that the following will do what you want.

```
var firstNonMatch = result
    .SelectMany(t => t.Header.Select(h => h.ResultMessage)) // convert list of responses into list of nested headers
    .FirstOrDefault(t => !matches.Contains(t));             // pick the first header that doesn't match (or null if no match)
```

Comment: I tried that but get error at .Select(**t** =>"A local or paramater 't' cannot be declared in this scope because that name is used in enclosing local scope to define local or parameter."  So I changed that t to r...gonna run it and see if it works.

Comment: @Rowan Have not checked the logic, but the error you got is because of the reuse of the `t =>` in `SelectMany(t => t.Header.Select(t => ...` Inside the `Select` the compiler does not know if `t` is the object declared inside the `SelectMany` or  the `Select`. The error should go away if you `.SelectMany(t => t.Header.Select(h => h.ResultMessage))`

Comment: Sorry, I was using .Net 6/C# 10 and it seemed to be okay with what I wrote.  I'll update my answer to make things more explicit.  The repeated use of "t" is not good even if the compiler is good with it.